# Python - shortening an if / for loop

Tags: python, coding-style, if-statement, for-loop, iterator

I've got a few lines of code for iterating over a dict within a list and I'm looking to shorten it. It works perfectly as is, but seems like too much code and I'm trying to get a feel for how to keep code efficient in Python (or in general really).

```
for d in dev['devices']:
    if d['name'] == devName:
        devFound = True
        break
```

The structure of 'dev' is a bit confusing but for the data I care about:
dev (dict) > devices (list) > 0-n (dict)

the value 'name' is a key within the inner numbered dict (varies depending on the search value elsewhere) which needs to be checked against a user input (devName)

Any input much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the same, only rewritten with some built-in function and a generator:

```
devFound = any(d['name'] == devName for d in dev['devices'])
```

Comment: PEP 8 no likey the space after `any`.  Care to fix it for an upvote?

Answer (score 4):

you could try with the [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
any(d for d in dev["devices"] if d['name'] == devName)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, looks like the same idea as @doublep but worded slightly differently. thanks!

Comment: I prefer doublep's solution because it puts the truth test up front, which seems to make more sense with `any`.  I do like that you linked to the docs, so +1 anyway.

Comment: @SG84: This one is probably a bit more efficient, but a bit less straightforward.

Comment: @Cédric Julien: I really don't see the point of writing a generator expression that returns matching `d`s (the `d` after `any`), as the contents of a matching `d` does not matter.  I therefore find this solution confusing.  On top of that, it fails if `dev["devices"]` contains mapping objects whose truth value is False (see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)–while this would be quite unusual, this is not officially precluded.

Comment: @doublep: Cédric's solution is indeed faster.  But why?  it looks to me like both iterators perform the same operations, namely tests on `d['name']`…

Comment: @EOL: With Cédric's solution iteration basically stops on the first found item.  All looping is done inside the runtime, in highly optimized C code.  In my example, on the other hand, on each iteration some Python code is evaluated and, while trivial, it's still not as fast as the "built-in" `if`.

Comment: @EOL: To think, it's not quite as that (still some Python code here too), but the basic idea is correct.  My solution involves "a bit more Python", where more items are "passed" from the generator to `any()` function.  Whereas with Cédric's solution items with wrong names never make it to generator output.

Comment: @doublep: Yeah, the speed up indeed comes from the fact that at most one term is output in Cédric's solution; this can be seen in the disassembled code that I put in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on Cédric Julien's answer, because it can fail in some (rare) cases:

```
any(True for d in dev["devices"] if d['name'] == devName)
```

Here is a (admittedly unusual, but possible) case that illustrates while `any(True …)` gives a correct result while `any(d …)` does not:

```
>>> class special_dict(dict):
...     def __nonzero__(self):
...         return False  # All special_dict objects are False
...     
>>> dev = {'devices': [special_dict(name="DEVNAME") for _ in xrange(10)]}
>>> any(d for d in dev["devices"] if d['name'] == "DEVNAME")  # Incorrect
False
>>> any(True for d in dev["devices"] if d['name'] == "DEVNAME")  # Correct
True
```

In fact, `special_dict` objects evaluate to False, so it does not make sense to test the truth value of `d`, in `any()`.  Using `True` works, though.

**PS**: Timing tests indicate that the `any(True … for … if … == …)` approach is faster than the nice `any(… == … for …)` solution of doublep:

```
python -m timeit -s "dev = {'devices': [{'name': 'BADNAME'} for _ in xrange(100)]}" "any(d['name'] == 'DEVNAME' for d in dev['devices'])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.3 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "dev = {'devices': [{'name': 'BADNAME'} for _ in xrange(100)]}" "any(True for d in dev['devices'] if d['name'] == 'DEVNAME' )"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.42 usec per loop
```

The reason is that the second generator returns at most one value (True).  This can be seen by disassembling the Python code for the two generators:

```
In [8]: def f(my_list):
   ...:     return any(x == 11 for x in my_list)
In [12]: f.func_code.co_consts[1]
Out[12]: <code object <genexpr> at 0x1041f98b0, file "<ipython-input-8-384ce7986872>", line 2>
In [13]: dis.dis(_)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                17 (to 23)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (11)
             15 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 YIELD_VALUE         
             19 POP_TOP             
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

This code contains `YIELD_VALUE` and `POP_TOP`, which take additional time, compared to the version of this answer:

```
In [14]: def g(my_list):
   ....:     return any(True for x in my_list if x == 11)

In [15]: g.func_code.co_consts[1]
Out[15]: <code object <genexpr> at 0x1041f9630, file "<ipython-input-14-735c68947d80>", line 2>
In [16]: dis.dis(g.func_code.co_consts[1])
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                23 (to 29)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (11)
             15 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        3
             21 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             24 YIELD_VALUE         
             25 POP_TOP             
             26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: you're right about the case of d is not trustable to be true (I had a case with a C binding that was not handling `__nonzero__` properly). Beside this, the fact it is faster is surprising me.